# Submitting action with my jQuery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-events

Here is my script and I don't understand why it don't work because it's very basic instructions...

Can anyone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bouton, #supprimer").button();
    $("#form").submit(function(event){
        if (confirm("ATTENTION : Cette action est irréversible, êtes vous certains de vouloir supprimer "+ <%= membre.getCn() %> +"?"))
        {
            alert("Utilisateur supprimé !");
        }
        else{
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: there no msgbox... that delete user without alert

Comment: Could you show some of the HTML for the form and the button(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is where you out the string from server script.

Use quotes to make the string you out to convert to javascript string. Or you can do it inline.

Use

```
confirm("ATTENTION : Cette action est irréversible, êtes vous certains de vouloir supprimer "+ "<%= membre.getCn() %>" +"?")
```

OR

```
confirm("ATTENTION : Cette action est irréversible, êtes vous certains de vouloir supprimer <%= membre.getCn() %>?")
```

instead

Answer (score 3):

The

```
..primer "+ <%= membre.getCn() %> +"?...
```

is wrong. You need to change into either

```
..primer <%= membre.getCn() %> ?...
```

or:

```
..primer "+ "<%= membre.getCn() %>" +"?...
```

You are mixing javascript and jsp here...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the argument being passed to confirm statement.
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".bouton, #supprimer").button();
        $("#form").submit(function(event){
            if (confirm("ATTENTION : Cette action est irréversible, êtes vous certains de vouloir supprimer <%= membre.getCn() %> ?"))
            {
                alert("Utilisateur supprimé !");
            }
            else{
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must return true or false

ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bouton, #supprimer").button();
    $("#form").submit(function(event){
        if (confirm("ATTENTION : Cette action est irréversible, êtes vous certains de vouloir supprimer "+ <%= membre.getCn() %> +"?"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: no because the jquery stop event method is event.preventDefault(); not need to return anything